# MySQL: Update when pair NOT IN list of pairs (no primary key)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this problem, but I'm having a bit of brain block in figuring it out.

### Background

I have a table with the following schema (abridged, since in reality the data is created by a join from multiple tables):

```
Order |  Item  |  Shipped

1        1         N
1        2         N
2        1         N
2        5         N
5        6         N
5        2         N
        ...
```

Notes on the schema:

- Each line is uniquely identified by a order+item, but this is not set up as a primary key.
- Further, there are no primary keys on the table, nor can I add one (the MySQL DB is a blind dump from a legacy system).

### The Problem

I need a way to set the `Shipped` column to `'Y'` IF the order+item pair does not exist in a list of order+item pairs.

In other words, I will have a PHP script elsewhere producing something like (edited for the sake of readability):

```
array(
  'Order1' => array(1),
  'Order5' => array(2, 6)
);
```

When I run a query, I should get the following table structure:

```
Order |  Item  |  Shipped

1        1         N
1        2         Y
2        1         Y
2        5         Y
5        6         N
5        2         N
        ...
```

The "intuitive" solution of

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Shipped='Y'
WHERE
Order NOT IN (1, 5)
AND Item NOT IN (1, 2, 6);
```

obviously doesn't work (since it wouldn't mark, for example, *Item #1* in *Order #2* as shipped).

Comment: @RyanVincent If an item exists in the list of order+item pairs, then the item has _not_ shipped. Thus, the default state of everything is for `Shipped` to be marked `'N'`, and anything that doesn't appear in the list should be changed to `'Y'`.

Comment: You have to iterate this array and execute query in each iteration;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I'm trying to avoid a brute-force (e.g., PHP or SQL cursor) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Shipped='Y'
WHERE (order, item) not in((1,2), (2,1)... )
```

((1,2), (2,1)... )  == your list  .. could be the result of a proper select or a proper string

Comment: Does `mysql` support multi-column comparisons?

Comment: I had no idea MySQL supported this syntax. It seems to be working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of conditions based on your input arrays:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Shipped='Y'
WHERE NOT
 ( 
   ( Order  = 1 AND Item IN (1))
  OR
   ( Order  = 5 AND Item IN (2,6))
 )
```